# Beamer - How can I get title paper formatting on other pages?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, themes

So I have multiple sections in my Beamer slide deck. I want to section off each section by having before it a title page for that section.

I am using the Copenhagen/Wolverine combo. So akin to this:
http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/large/Copenhagen-wolverine-default-01.png

To be fair, all I actually want is to have text in a yellow box, like in the picture, on other pages with the text being different per section. How can I do this?

Comment: Stupid solution: you could split the presentation for each section and join the results into one pdf. For images please use the TeX.SX specific upload (in the editor there is a possibility to upload images). Some users my refrain from visiting third party sites. Also this ensures that the image is still available in the future.

Comment: You should also provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your question which shows your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if your are looking for `\sectionpage`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}[plain,c]
        \sectionpage
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is brilliant, and absolutely what I was after. However, a quick question, how can I remove the Section 1, Section 2, etc.?

Comment: @Andre You can remove these by redefining the section page template.